# Display auto complete suggestions in sublime?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I use atom for typing my Latex documents. One feature I really loved is auto complete suggestions.

I recently came across sublime which is comparatively fast and loved it. Even though it has auto complete feature, it doesn't show the suggestions while typing, i.e., one have to press tab to cycle the auto complete suggestions and doesn't display as in atom. I want to know if there is a way to display the auto complete suggestions in real time similar to atom?

Comment: What language are you using? For me it comes up as I type

Comment: I mainly use it for Latex (has a lot of text) as mentioned. But I need to display the auto complete suggestions in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer while looking at https://github.com/Zinggi/DictionaryAutoComplete.

So, adding "auto_complete_selector": "source, text" to settings-user file does the trick

Answer (score 1):

This might depend on which package is handling the autocompletion. Usually there is a customizable setting for autocomplete triggers:

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/completion-triggers/13139/2

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/auto-complete-triggers/3751/4

```
"auto_complete_triggers": [
   { "characters": " ", "selector": "source.python"}
]
```